# Postfix: e-mail is not received on server mailbox. Forward does work

Tags: postfix, centos6.4

For this server I'm running virtualmin. It comes with postfix.
One of my users is complaining he's not receiving all the e-mails.
To check this I let postfix forward his e-mails to another e-mail address (gmail).
He is receiving the e-mails in gmail, not in postfix.
The messages are not marked as spam. The e-mails can't be found anywhere.

Example of the logs:

```
[root@server]# grep ***messageid9F63AA8003***@***.gbl /var/log/maillog
Sep 24 12:10:44 server postfix/cleanup[1827]: 6248E3BC0243: message-id=<***messageid9F63AA8003***@***.gbl>
Sep 24 12:10:44 server spamd[16387]: spamd: processing message <***messageid9F63AA8003***@***.gbl> for mail.account:524
Sep 24 12:10:46 server spamd[16387]: spamd: result: . -2 - FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,RP_MATCHES_RCVD scantime=1.4,size=2198,user=mail.account,uid=524,required_score=4.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=335,mid=<***messageid9F63AA8003***@***.gbl>,autolearn=ham
Sep 24 12:10:46 server postfix/cleanup[1827]: 8BD433BC056E: message-id=<***messageid9F63AA8003***@***.gbl>
```

This looks good, so I'm looking further:

```
[root@server]# grep 8BD433BC056E /var/log/maillog
Sep 24 12:10:46 server postfix/cleanup[1827]: 8BD433BC056E: message-id=<***messageid9F63AA8003***@***.gbl>
Sep 24 12:10:46 server postfix/local[1828]: 6248E3BC0243: to=<mail.user@hostname.server.com>, orig_to=<mail@account.com>, relay=local, delay=2, delays=0.2/0/0/1.8, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 8BD433BC056E)
Sep 24 12:10:46 server postfix/qmgr[26692]: 8BD433BC056E: from=<user-from@hotmail.com>, size=2252, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 24 12:10:47 server postfix/smtp[1850]: 8BD433BC056E: to=<userforward@gmail.com>, orig_to=<mail@account.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.26]:25, delay=2.5, delays=1.8/0/0.18/0.49, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1380017236 l42si26334755eef.298 - gsmtp)
Sep 24 12:10:47 server postfix/qmgr[26692]: 8BD433BC056E: removed
```

Here postfix claims it delivered the e-mail to the mailbox. Though it does not show.
What can I still have done wrong? Any hints?

Comment: How are you confirming the user is not getting mail?

Comment: The user calls me every day when he receives a mail on the gmail account that was sent to the user account but was not arrived in the user account. The user is trustworthy ...

Comment: Are you keeping a local copy of the user's mail when you forward it?

Answer (score 1):

What you see in above snippet is log when postfix **forward** email without keeping local copy. In plain terms, forwarding was same with changing recipient of email.

Above snippet contains to queue-id *6248E3BC0243* and *8BD433BC056E*. When postfix get email from hotmail, it gives queue-id *6248E3BC0243*. Because you set forwarding, so postfix forward it and logs the action in  this line.

> Sep 24 12:10:46 server postfix/local[1828]: 6248E3BC0243: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=2, delays=0.2/0/0/1.8, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 8BD433BC056E)

That line tells us that postfix successfully (status=sent) forward it to another email address. Postfix gives queue-id *8BD433BC056E* for the forwarded email.

Of course you should gives us more info (like this maillog line) when user receive email but the email doesn't exist in his mailbox.